# iOS app crash with symbol not found error

Tags: ios, crash, symbols

I've deployed my application on my iOS 7 device and my application crashes during the run.
When I get the crash log, I've the following error :

Dyld Error Message:

```
  Symbol not found: _MKMapRectIsNull
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/1945A90E-28A7-4799-8D6E-C145A593D553/Perfectrun.app/Perfectrun
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
  Dyld Version: 212.3.2
```

How can I solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: You need add the mapkit framework if you haven't and also import the mapkit in your header file.

Comment: Seems to be a lot better including this missing header ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the MapKit framework?
Go to Target > Build Phases > Link with Binary Libraries > Plus button. 
Search for MapKit and add the framework to your project.
If you have already imported the framework try deleting it and importing it again.

Comment: Thanks but always the same error... Is there another way to find what is wrong ?